Trouble setting es2022 in a new node js project
Hopefully you'll know what's happening.
I'm using a express project ts generator by seanpmaxwell to generate a new project
Node version I'm using is v20.11.1
It works just great, but I want to use es2022 on this (just want to get top level await working)
I have spent 3 days on this and its a total headache
I run yarn dev and this is the output

this is the package.json:
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type":"module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx ts-node build.ts",
    "lint": "npx eslint --ext .ts src/",
    "lint:tests": "npx eslint --ext .ts spec/",
    "start": "node -r module-alias/register ./dist/src --env=production",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "test": "nodemon --config ./spec/nodemon.json",
    "test:no-reloading": "npx ts-node --files -r tsconfig-paths/register ./spec"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "watch": [
      "src"
    ],
    "ext": "ts, html",
    "ignore": [
      "src/public"
    ],
    "exec": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --files -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src"
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@src": "dist"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hocuspocus/server": "^2.11.3",
    "@types/express-ws": "^3.0.4",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "express-ws": "^5.0.2",
    "helmet": "^7.1.0",
    "inserturlparams": "^1.0.1",
    "jet-logger": "^1.3.1",
    "jet-paths": "^1.0.6",
    "jet-validator": "^1.1.1",
    "jsonfile": "^6.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.3",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.3",
    "ts-command-line-args": "^2.5.1",
    "y-protocols": "^1.0.6",
    "yjs": "^13.6.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/find": "^0.2.4",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/jsonfile": "^6.1.4",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.9",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.2",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "find": "^0.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
    "jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.3"
  }
}

and this is the tsconfig.json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
 },
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es2022",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "es2022",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */

    /* Advanced Options */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                     /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": [
        "src/*",
        "db/*"
      ],
    },
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "db/*.ts",
    "spec/**/*.ts",
    "build.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "src/public/"
  ]
}

If you got any other way to start a express project using js and latest es (or es2022) I'm open to new ideas, so far this is the most complete generator I found but I haven't been able to progress further.

Which version of node do you use? node --version

added to the post, the version of node I'm using its v20.11.1

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
